# capture https requests and responses made using .NET HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse by fiddler

Tags: .net, httpwebrequest, fiddler, httpwebresponse

Is there any way I can hook Fiddler up to capture https requests and responses made using .NET HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse?

I have application that requests some url's.

Next code help me capture all http requsts using fiddler

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);
```

But I have problems when application get https requests.

Comment: Check out this article:  
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

Comment: Thank you for reply Sten Petrov, but this topic describe how setup fiddler for work with https at all. I can capture ordinary browsers https requests using fiddler, but face with problem with capturing https request made by my application.

Comment: Correct me if something is wrong.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean when you say "have problems". What exactly happens? Do you get exceptions in the Application? Do you see only CONNECT tunnels in the Fiddler UI? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-DOTNET

Comment: Did you properly install a certificate for Fiddler or make your application ignore SSL certificate errors?  Try adding `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Validator` to your app with `bool Validator (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }` - this will make the runtime ignore any SSL certificate errors.

Comment: Thank you for replies. Before reading that I want to explain my problem. Sorry that I haven't done this early. I request url that begins with https and executing  webRequest.GetResponse() gives exception "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." with inner exception "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure."

Comment: Martin Baulig Thank you very much. This works for me. My appreciation is measureless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is in adding

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Validator
```

with

```
bool Validator (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }
```

thanks for  Martin Baulig